# The maximum and minimum of a function over the unit circle in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to calculate the maximum and minimum for the absolute value of the function
$$
f(z)=z^3-a
$$

for $z$ in the unit circle (center in origin) of $\mathbb{C}$ and $a\in\mathbb{C}, a\neq 0$. I tried to do this using some calculus argument but I ended up having to find the maximum and minimum of the function $\alpha \cos (3t)+\beta \sin (3t)$, where $t\in[0,2\pi]$ and $a=\alpha+i\beta$.

I'm now trying a geometric approach. Consider the line passing through $a$ and the origin in the plane. Since $g(z)=z^3$ restricted to the unit circle has its image on the unit circle, what I need to find are points $z$ in the domain of $g$ which images are the closer and farther from $a$ as possible. Obviosly those are the cubic roots of $\dfrac{-a}{|a|}$ and $\dfrac{a}{|a|}$, respectively.

Therefore, the maximum and minimum of $f$ over the unit circle would be $||a|+1|$ and $||a|-1|$, rescpectively.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: It's a little hard to understand how you're matching up closer/further with min/max. $|g(z)-a|$ is the distance between $g(z)$ and $a$, not between $g(z)$ and $-a$. Also, there's really no reason to talk about the supremum and infimum—since this is a continuous function on a compact set, it has a maximum and a minimum.

Comment: I corrected the minus sign; it wasn't supposed to be there.

Comment: I meant the supremum and infimum of the set of absolut values of the images of $f$, which coincides with its maximum and minimum.

Comment: I think you may be confused about the meanings of those words. A set can have a max/min or a sup/inf, and the notion for a function is derived from the one for a set. The maximum of a function is the maximum of its image; its supremum is the supremum of its image. If there is a maximum[minimum] then that is always the supremum[infimum], but sometimes there will be a supremum[infimum] when there is no maximum[minimum].

Comment: Yes, I know this very well; since we're in the compact case the maximum and minimum exists and coincides with the supremum and infimum. Could you please pay attention to the argumentation and not to this kind of detail?

Comment: Other than correcting you to say max/min of $|f|$, I would say your geometric approach is good.

Answer (score 3):

The argument is correct, but here is the (inferior) calculus version: write $a=re^{i\theta}$. Since $$|z^3-a|=|(e^{-i\theta/3}z)^3-r|$$ it follows that the maximum / minimum of $|z^3-a|$ are the same as for $|z^3-r|$. In terms of $z=e^{it}$, the square of $|z^3-r|$ is 
$$(\cos 3t-r)^2+\sin^2 3t = 1+r^2-2r\cos 3t \tag1$$
The extreme values of cosine are $\pm 1$, which correspond to $(1\pm r)^2$ in (1).

Comment: Shouldn't there be an "a" term on (1)?

Comment: @GustavoMarra No, I meant the square of $|z^3-r|$. Fixed now.